# Security rate update on Sonarqube version 6.7 with embedded database

Tags: sonarqube

I'm using the 6.7 version of Sonarqube with embedded database to evaluate it.

I got the Security rate "E" for a project because of some Blocker vulnerabilites found.

I changed the Vulnerability issues status from Blocker to "False positive", so I expected the Security rate would change to "A", but it remained "E", even after I restarted it.

I noticed that the project's home page still shows the same number of vulnerabilies, even after I have changed their status to False positive.

Is it possible that the Security rate is not being updated because I'm using the embedded database?

Thank you.

Comment: Did you perform a new analysis?

Comment: I didn't perform a new analysis. Sorry for the late answer. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

With SonarQube 6.7, when you perform an operation in the Web application - like flagging an issue as False-Positive or Won't-Fix, the metrics are not updated automatically on the fly. You have to run a new analysis to have them refreshed in the UI.

We are aware that this behaviour is not what users would expect, and actually this is something we are currently working on for SonarQube 7.0 (you can see more details on the [related Feature ticket](https://jira.sonarsource.com/browse/MMF-744)).